# jtable error loading in IIS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-jtable

I have `jtable` working in debug mode from visual Studio using `iisExpress`, but when i publish it and install it on IIS it doesn't work any more.

the jtable doesn't even show when in IIS

Can anyone give me an help on this?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Filtering.aspx.cs"   Inherits="jTableWithAspNetWebForms.Filtering" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Filtering With jTable and ASP.NET Web Forms</title>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/themes/metroblue/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<!-- jTable style file -->
<link href="/Scripts/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />

<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>

<script src="/Scripts/jtablesite.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- A helper library for JSON serialization -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jtable/external/json2.js"> </script>
<!-- Core jTable script file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>
<!-- ASP.NET Web Forms extension for jTable -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jtable/extensions/jquery.jtable.aspnetpagemethods.js"></script>
<style>
    div.filtering
    {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #EEE;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="site-container">
    <div class="filtering">
        <form runat="server">
        <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></label>
        <label>
            City:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCities" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </label>
        <button type="submit" id="LoadRecordsButton">
            Load records</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="StudentTableContainer">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jtable plugin
        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'The Student List',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/Filtering.aspx/StudentListByFilter',
                createAction: '/Filtering.aspx/CreateStudent',
                updateAction: '/Filtering.aspx/UpdateStudent',
                deleteAction: '/Filtering.aspx/DeleteStudent'
            },
            fields: {
                StudentId: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                }
                RecordDate: {
                    title: 'Record date',
                    width: '15%',
                    type: 'date',
                    displayFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    sorting: false //This column is not sortable!
                }
            }
        });

        //Re-load records when user click 'load records' button.
        $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load', {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                cityId: $('#<% = ddlCities.ClientID %>').val()
            });
        });

        //Load all records when page is first shown
        $('#LoadRecordsButton').click();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: U r saying it is running on local then try to add (../ ) before all script, links and jTable actions.

Comment: Unfortunnatly it dosn't work. I stll have the '$' is undefined

Comment: Solved. Its only take out the firs backslash. It looks like this
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: good @Carlos Santos.